# How can i get the content of head tag in html

Tags: c#, html

I already initialized my _chaptername in the top of my code as

```
private static string _chapterName = "";
```

but still i receive an error that an object reference is not set to an instance of an object. **What initialization should be done in my case?** I encounter no problem if my input is multiple files, but when my input is only 1 this error occur(object reference is not set to an instance of an object).

```
var content = string.Empty;
            content =  File.ReadAllText(inputName);
            if (content.Contains("<h1"))
            {
                _chapterName = inputXDoc.XPathSelectElement("//h1").Value;
            }
            else if (content.Contains("<h2"))
            {
                _chapterName = inputXDoc.XPathSelectElement("//h2").Value;
            }
            else if (content.Contains("<h3"))
            {
                _chapterName = inputXDoc.XPathSelectElement("//h3").Value;
            }
            else if (content.Contains("<h4"))
            {
                _chapterName = inputXDoc.XPathSelectElement("//h4").Value;
            }
```

Comment: XPathSelectElement could return a null value if it doesn't find any match. Directly using the Value property will lead to this problem. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Put a break point on `content` and `inputXDoc` my guess is one of these is null

Comment: I already check my file with the target of my XPathSelectElement<h3 class="sgc-5">Blah blah<sup class="fn-num"><a id="r_fn1" href="#fn1">1</a></sup></h3>

Comment: My code should return **Blah blah**. but it returns null

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the issue is that your conditions are checking for "<h*", but then your XPathSelectElement is looking for "//h*", which doesn't actually exist in your input. Fix that up and it should work

Comment: @KevinWells, my code works in multiple html, but in one html file, this cause an error.

Comment: working demo is here http://rextester.com/HNYT47794

Comment: @Steve here is the working code.. http://rextester.com/HNYT47794d

Comment: here http://rextester.com/TAL82060